# How to show a list in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to show a list of "roles" from the membership/role tables

My controller is:

```
' GET: /Admin/Index
Function Index() As ActionResult
    Dim model = New AdminRoles()
    model.Roles = Roles.GetAllRoles()
    Return View(model)
End Function
```

My model is:

```
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class AdminRoles
    Public Property Roles() As String()
End Class

Public Class AdminRolesDBContext
  Inherits DbContext
  Public Property AdminRole() As DbSet(Of AdminRoles)
End Class
```

My view is:

```
@ModelType IEnumerable(Of MPConversion.AdminRoles)
@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Index"
End Code
<h2>Index</h2>
<p>    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")</p>
<table><tr><th>Role</th><th></th></tr>
@For Each item In Model
    Dim currentItem = item
    @<tr>
    <td>currentitem.Roles</td>
        <td>
            @*@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", New With {.id = currentItem.PrimaryKey}) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", New With {.id = currentItem.PrimaryKey}) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", New With {.id = currentItem.PrimaryKey})*@
        </td>
    </tr>
Next
</table>
```

However I get ther error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MPConversion.AdminRoles', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MPConversion.AdminRoles]'.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You should send IEnumerable of AdminRoles instead of single AdminRoles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply use

```
@ModelType MPConversion.AdminRoles
```

and then

```
 @For Each item In Model.Roles
```

Your AdminRoles class contain some kind of collection returned by Roles.GetAllRoles(), but the object itself (AdminRoles) is not a collection, and doesn't implement IEnumerable at all.

**Updated**
To optimize a bit:

Cotroller

```
Function Index() As ActionResult
    IEnumerable(Of String) allRoles = Roles.GetAllRoles() // modify the GetAllRoles method
    Return View(allRoles)
End Function
```

View:

```
@ModelType IEnumerable(Of String)
@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Index"
End Code
<h2>Index</h2>
<p>    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")</p>
<table><tr><th>Role</th><th></th></tr>
@For Each item In Model
    <tr>
    <td>@item</td>
    @* Commented part deleted for brevity *@
    </tr>
Next
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you - this is helping me a lot.  How do I then display the roleName - it doesn't appear when I use @item.roles

Comment: @MarkTait: each `item` inside your `foreach` loop is a role, so you don't have to write `@item.roles`. For each `item` to obtain the name of the role, you should write `@item.Name`, supposing that `Role` class has a property called `Name`

Comment: @MarkTait: Also, `Dim currentItem = item` has no point to exist

Comment: Hi - ok, found out this seems to work: @currentItem.ToString - but is the way I am doing it with the model view and controller, the best way??  What would be the recommended way, as mine seems a bit messy?  Thanks again.

Comment: I can see that too - I was just trying to copy the format of the VS generated templates.

Comment: themarcuz - that's why I'm confused - my class AdminRoles does have a property "Roles" - but that is not appearing - which suggests although this is working, it's really not the right way to do it.

Comment: Well, given that `AdminRoles` only contains an array of string, you really don't need it. Modify `Roles.GetAllRoles()` in order to return an `IEnumerable(of String)`, and then use it as your model. See updated answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

Your class adminRoles does not implement IEnumerable.